# Cocoa touch Framework with Unit tests

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, xcode6, xctest

In Xcode 6 with Objective-C:
When I create a Cocoa Touch Framework the project has already a unit test target.

Assuming I have the following class and unit test case in my framework:

```
//Framework
@interface MyClass : NSObject
- (NSString*)greetings;
@end

@implementation MyClass 

- (NSString*)greetings {
  return @"Hello";
}
@end

// Test class
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import "MyClass.h"
@interface MyClassTests : XCTestCase
@end

@implementation MyClassTests
- (void)testGreetings {
  MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
  XCTAssertTrue([[myClass greetings] isEqualToString:@"Hello"]);
}
@end
```

When I try to run the test I get:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in MyClassTests.o

Why is the test target not finding my classes? I can't figure out what is wrong. I assume that the Xcode template would set up everything correctly.

Comment: I don't see any interface declaration of your class called MyClass, if you've defined your interface elsewhere, just import that header

Comment: @deathhorse I added the missing lines. Only importing is not solving the problem. Unit testing for Cocoa Touch frameworks seems to be different than for normal Apps.

Comment: Hmm..Probably you're building your framework on "device" architectures like armv7, armv7s, etc but not for simulator. try to run the same test on device

Comment: I've created a cocoa touch framework right now, but I have no problems running tests on it. Probably the linking of your classes or setup of your project is broken..

Comment: I've created a complete new project. Either changing the "Valid architectures" in the normal and test target or "Build Active Arch only" is not fixing the problem. Building the test target for device gives the same error. Running unit test on device is not possible. I can't understand why a complete new project is not working for me.

Comment: @Sebastian, If you make MyClass a member of the unit test target, does that fix things? When I get a link error like yours, I find that making the app classes members of the unit test target make the link errors go away.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk When I add the `.m` file to the unit test target the error is gone. I thought it is not necessary anymore to add the classes to the unit test target. I think in normal Apps this should not be done.

Comment: @Sebastian, Adding the app classes to the unit test target isn't encouraged. I add the app classes to the unit test target only when I get link errors running the tests.

Answer (score 0):

you add this x86_64 architecture in Build setting -> Valid Architecture x86_64 and try it. It can be work.

Refer the architecture:

```
armv7: Used in the oldest iOS 7-supporting devices
armv7s: As used in iPhone 5 and 5C
arm64: For the 64-bit ARM processor in iPhone 5S
i386: For the 32-bit simulator
x86_64: Used in 64-bit simulator
```